# Why can my SPA not get authenticated through WebAPI which redirects to https://login.microsoftonline.com?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

1. I have a SPA which calls a .NET Core WebAPI. (source code at bottom)
2. The WebAPI uses Azure Active Directory Authentication (service.AddAzureAD).
3. The SPA does not do any authentication nor any authorization before calling the WebAPI.

When the WebAPI sees that the call from the SPA is not authenticated, the WebAPI redirects to the login page after which the WebAPI returns the result to the SPA.
(Looking at this picture it seems this is not possible ... too many redirects.)

[image: Flow between SPA - WebAPI - Azure AD Authentication]

When directly calling the WebAPI directly, e.g. `https://localhost:44387/api/values` the browser is redirected to the Azure login page. After logging in the API is executed successfully.

When the SPA calls the WebAPI, the following error happens (Chrome, Firefox and Edge)

**Error Summary**

```
The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://login.microsoftonline.com
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**Firefox error**

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: 
The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/…YH3fMelA&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0.
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

**Chrome error**

```
Access to fetch at 
'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44387%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637154642948775901&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0' 
(redirected from 'https://localhost:44387/api/values') 
from origin 'https://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, 
set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

**Edge error** (in German ... basically the same as the Chrome error)

```
SEC7120: [CORS] Der Ursprung 
"https://localhost:8080" konnte "null" im 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header für die cross-origin -Ressource bei
"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44387%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=...&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0" 
 nicht finden.
```

---

**SPA Code**

```
function component() {
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  element.innerHTML = 'Hello world';
  return element;
}

async function callAPI() {
  const data = await fetchValues();
  console.log('data', data);
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  element.innerHTML = `API response: ${data.toString()}`;
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}

function fetchValues() {
  const url =  'https://localhost:44387/api/values';
  return fetch(url, {
    // mode: 'no-cors',
    // referrer: '',
    // referrerPolicy: 'unsafe-url',
    // redirect: 'follow'
  })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('response -> ', response);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('data -> ', data);
      return data;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('error:', err);
      return err;
    });
}

document.body.appendChild(component());
callAPI();
```

**WebAPI Startup code** (call AddMicrosoftIdentityPlatformAuthentication is from [Microsoft.Identity.Web](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/faa94fd49c2da46b22d6694c4f5c5895795af26d/Microsoft.Identity.Web/WebAppServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L33) )

```
namespace ns
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public const string ScopeUserRead = "User.Read";
        public const string BearerAuthorizationScheme = "Bearer";
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();

            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityPlatformAuthentication(Configuration);

            services.AddControllers();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseCors(builder =>
          builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
         .AllowAnyHeader()
         .AllowAnyMethod());
            app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions().HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility());
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
            app.UseStaticFiles();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that it is login page of Microsoft that does not allow any cors.  I think what you need have your API return `return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Not Authenticated");` and redirect on SPA to the login page.